# I want to split a value which is stored in a String while using window handles

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, window-handles

This is my code

```
Set<String> winHandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(winHandle);
```

I want to split `winHandle`. The value I get when i print the winHandle is like this

```
[{0dd5d2e3-da7f-4a57-ad06-52c19336d3c6}, {a32fd7a5-040f-488f-8bc0-64d9a4496509}]
```

I want to select the Second Value `{a32fd7a5-040f-488f-8bc0-64d9a4496509}`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want second value instead of first one? Remember that Sets doesn't guarantee any order of elements.

Comment: If you know the exact value which you need from the Set you can iterate and compare that as its String and get that value.

Comment: Could you generalise the question? Is it the specific value you want or the last value in the winhandle?

Comment: i need to pass the control to next window. The second value is of that window i required. That window contains the value i have to verify.@Pshemo

Comment: actually i want the control to be in the new tab. The second value shows the id of new window. I need to open that window and perform required actions.@Iridann

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is "how to get second item in set" you would need to iterate over elements until you will get element you are looking for.

So your code can look like

```
Iterator<String> it = winHandle.iterator();
it.next();//read and ignore first element
String value = it.next();//read and store second element
```

If your question is more general like "how to get *last* element" you could use

```
String last = null;
Iterator<String> it = winHandle.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    last = it.next();
}
//when loop will end `last` will hold last element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Method driver.getWindowHandles() is often used for switching between tabs/windows of browser. If your question is "how to switch into the last opened tab/window" you could try this code:

```
Set<String> oldWindowsSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
//action that produce opening new tab/window (ex. webElement.click())
Set<String> newWindowsSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
newWindowsSet.removeAll(oldWindowsSet);
String newWindowHandle = newWindowsSet.iterator().next();
driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
```